# Use Homebrew version of OpenSSH for incoming connections

Tags: homebrew, ssh

I'm trying to get my system (Ventura) to use the Homebrew version of OpenSSH for incoming connections, so I can ssh into that machine using hardware keys. The built-in `sshd` does not accept hardware keys as authentication. If I manually run `sshd` using `/opt/homebrew/sbin/sshd -d`, for example, the Homebrew version of `sshd` starts and runs using the config file at `/opt/homebrew/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, which is the behavior I want. How do I make this permanent, though? Ideally I would want Homebrew `sshd` running on a non-standard port and then just turn off built-in ssh.

Comment: Turn off ssh in settings, add a startup plist to start homebrew sshd.

Comment: @JamesRisner: Can you please elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: @Ramprasad I'll add an answer over the weekend.

Comment: @Ramprasad There's a good tutorial here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html -- using the "Hello, world" example, your array would contain a single item, `<string>/opt/homebrew/sbin/sshd</string>`