# Issues with ed25519-sk keys with ssh on Mac Ventura

Tags: ssh, ventura

I am unable to use ssh keys of type ed25519-sk (signed-and-send via Yubikeys) to login after an upgrade to Mac Ventura.

The only changes to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` are:

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Here are some steps I am taking to trouble-shoot this.

```
> ssh -V
OpenSSH_9.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1s  1 Nov 2022

> ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -f key_sk
Generating public/private ed25519-sk key pair.
You may need to touch your authenticator to authorize key generation.
...
# generates key_sk.pub and key_sk

> cat key_sk.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

> ssh-keygen -f key_rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
...
# generates key_rsa.pub and key_rsa

> cat key_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys


> ssh -i key_sk 127.0.0.1
ramprasad@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey).

> ssh -i key_rsa 127.0.0.1
# succeeds
```

For some excerpts from `ssh -vvv`:

```
> ssh -vvv -i key_rsa 127.0.0.1:
(snip)
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: key_rsa RSA SHA256:DQhukETfKbBFvL85ezp5oUijuK1uWIaECt4ZrpqxryU explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: key_rsa RSA SHA256:DQhukETfKbBFvL85ezp5oUijuK1uWIaECt4ZrpqxryU explicit
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey-hostbound-v00@openssh.com with RSA SHA256:DQhukETfKbBFvL85ezp5oUijuK1uWIaECt4ZrpqxryU
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:DQhukETfKbBFvL85ezp5oUijuK1uWIaECt4ZrpqxryU
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
Authenticated to 127.0.0.1 ([127.0.0.1]:22) using "publickey".
```

```
> ssh -vvv -i key_sk 127.0.0.1
(snip)
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: key_sk ED25519-SK SHA256:IsaG1C++pEjFEwyuO5SanrCtLq37xqVjJOizSKw5zL4 explicit authenticator
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ramprasad@127.0.0.1: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Would someone have an idea of what may be going on?

Comment: The following related question point out the issue. Mac Ventura's default ssh does not seem to support SK-type keys but Homebrew's open ssh does. Installing openssh via homebrew changes the ssh client but the Mac should be instructed to use the homebrew version of sshd for incoming connections and not the default `/usr/sbin/sshd`.  

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/450790/use-homebrew-version-of-openssh-for-incoming-connections